# server.close() gives "server not running" in afterEach mocha hook

Tags: express, mocha.js

I'm trying to run a test suite with mocha, the goal is to start the server beforeEach test case and then
close it afterEach test case.

But for some reason when the afterEach case ignites I get the following error:
Error [ERR_SERVER_NOT_RUNNING]: Server is not running.

The test case passes which means the server is up and running.

I Export the server like this from my app.js file:

```
var server = app.listen(3000, function () {
  var port = server.address().port;
  console.log("Example app listening at port %s", port);
});

module.exports = server; // Export server in order to use it in test files
```

My test file:

```
describe("loading express", function () {
  var server;
  before(function (done) {
    User.deleteMany(done);
  });

  beforeEach(function () {
    server = require("../app");
  });
  afterEach(function (done) {
    server.close(done);
  });
  describe("Create user account with valid email address", function () {
    describe("Route: POST /signup", () => {
      it("201 HAPPY PATH", (done) => {
        chai
          .request(server)
          .post("/signup")
          .send({
            email: "test23222@test.test",
            password: "12345678",
            firstname: "testtest",
            lastname: "testtest",
          })
          .end((err, res) => {
            res.should.have.status(201);
            done();
          });
      });
    });
  });
});
```

I believe I need to export a promise.

This is what I got so far:

```
var server = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
 app.listen(3000, function () {
  var port = server.address().port;
  console.log("Example app listening at port %s", port);
  resolve();
 });
}

module.exports = server; // Export server in order to use it in test files

in test suite:

var server = require('./app.js')

server.then(function() {
 ....
}
```

Comment: Why do you think `server = await require("../app")` would wait for server to start? `async/await` only works with promises.

Comment: Also `require` will cache the module. it makes no sense to do it inside `beforeEach` unless you somehow hijacked module loading algorithm.

Comment: the await / async was a typo before copying and pastying from another experiment, removed now.

Comment: OK, but still why do you expect server to be listening to the port immediately after you have required it. Your test might finish before it. You need to provide some way to wait for server to finish "listen" process before you proceed to the test.

Comment: I followed this guide: https://glebbahmutov.com/blog/how-to-correctly-unit-test-express-server/ but I guess I need to add a promise somewhere...

Comment: The article is quite old. And you are not following it to a letter. Author is using `supertest` library not `chai.request` that likely does something to wait for server to bind the port. Also once you read it to the end you will find that the author tried to actually bypass require cache mechanism.

Comment: I agree with you that I should look into a solution with a promise. I edited my main post with a promise example. Do you think this could work? Thank you for taking the time.

Comment: module.exports.promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    resolve(app.listen(3000));
}); ?

Comment: This might work but if forces all server consumers to be aware of this behaviour (the fact that server is actually a `Promise<Server>`). Might be inconvenient.

Comment: What do you recommend as a good working alternative?

Answer (score 0):

The server is closed by `chai-http` every time a request is served.
From the [chai-http docs](https://www.chaijs.com/plugins/chai-http/):

> If you want to keep the server open, perhaps if you’re making multiple requests, you must call `.keepOpen()` after `.request()`, and manually close the server down:

E.g:

```js
chai
  .request(server)
  .keepOpen() // <-- Here
  .post("/signup")
  .send({
    email: "test23222@test.test",
    password: "12345678",
    firstname: "testtest",
    lastname: "testtest",
  })
```